# Removed Objective-c files after porting them to Swift stuck to the project and reporting file:... warning: Missing file: ... is missing from

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode8

I deleted a number of Objective-c files after porting them to Swift. Yet they are now reported missing as in the following screenshot:
[image: files are missing from the work copy]
I checked them in the project file and they were not there, as well I committed the project without any result. Notwithstanding they are just warning they seem to abort the compilation at the end with:

> Command
>   /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc
>   failed with exit code 1

Strangely they are also reported on another project including the same git repository and they do not in a third independent one. I feel like it is a git problem, notwithstanding committing did not fix things.

Comment: Have you removed them from the Xcode project as well? Check for any red files in the navigator.

Comment: Sure, I first removed them from the project and then moved them to another folder as I had done ten of times before. There are no red files.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project? There are two types of clean (the second one is done while holding the option key), try both.

Comment: Yes, I both cleaned the project and deleted the derived folder. Those are the first things I do when I have problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing git add * and then committing got rid of the missing files warning. Unfortunately the error at the end remained, though, hinting to not being connected to that issue.